# How to sort a dataframe columns by the median of all its columns

Tags: r

How can I sort this datfarame by the median of its columns?

```
A    B    C

1    2    3
4    5    6
7    8    9
10   11   12
```

So, the output would be

```
C    B    A
3    2    1
6    5    4
9    8    7
12   11   10
```

I know, with this example, is easy to sort the dataframe by reverting the order of the columns, but, I would like to know how to sort the columns of this dataframe by the median of all of them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculate `median` column-wise and `order` :

```
df[order(-sapply(df, median))]

#   C  B  A
#1  3  2  1
#2  6  5  4
#3  9  8  7
#4 12 11 10
```

You can also use `colMedians` from `matrixStats` to get column-wise median.

```
df[order(-matrixStats::colMedians(as.matrix(df)))]
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(A = c(1L, 4L, 7L, 10L), B = c(2L, 5L, 8L, 11L), 
C = c(3L, 6L, 9L, 12L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another base R solution

```
> df[names(sort(-sapply(df,median)))]
   C  B  A
1  3  2  1
2  6  5  4
3  9  8  7
4 12 11 10
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
    summarise(across(everything(), median)) %>% 
    pivot_longer(everything()) %>%
    arrange(desc(value)) %>%
    pull(name) %>% 
    select(df, .)
```

---

Or using `base R` with `apply`

```
df[order(-apply(df, 2, median))]
#   C  B  A
#1  3  2  1
#2  6  5  4
#3  9  8  7
#4 12 11 10
```